# Numbering visits for each patient in a query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this query:

```
SELECT  R.ID,
        R.clm_FirstName + ' ' + R.clm_Surname2 AS 'Name and surname',
        R.clm_Age2 AS 'Age',
        V.ID AS 'VISIT ID',
        CONVERT(varchar, V.clm_VisitDate, 103) AS 'Visit date',
        M.clm_BMI AS 'BMI'
FROM    tblData_Registration R
        INNER JOIN tblData_Visit V ON R.ID=V.RegistrationID
        INNER JOIN tblData_Measurements M ON V.ID=M.VisitID
```

which gives me:

[image: Query results:]

I am trying to number VisitId as 1,2,3.... for each different patient, but I'm at a firm deadlock. Not sure where to go from here. Any pointers?

Thanks a million in advance.
Gav :)

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `rank` window function to achieve your goal :)

```
SELECT  R.ID,
    R.clm_FirstName + ' ' + R.clm_Surname2 AS 'Name and surname',
    R.clm_Age2 AS 'Age',
    rank() over (partition by R.ID order by V.ID) AS 'VISIT ID',
    CONVERT(varchar, V.clm_VisitDate, 103) AS 'Visit date',
    M.clm_BMI AS 'BMI'
FROM    tblData_Registration R
    INNER JOIN tblData_Visit V ON R.ID=V.RegistrationID
    INNER JOIN tblData_Measurements M ON V.ID=M.VisitID
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  R.ID,
        R.clm_FirstName + ' ' + R.clm_Surname2 AS 'Name and surname',
        R.clm_Age2 AS 'Age',
        V.ID AS 'VISIT ID',
        CONVERT(varchar, V.clm_VisitDate, 103) AS 'Visit date',
        M.clm_BMI AS 'BMI',
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY R.ID
                               ORDER BY V.clm_VisitDate,
                                        V.ID
                          )
                            AS clm_visit_number
FROM    tblData_Registration R
        INNER JOIN tblData_Visit V ON R.ID=V.RegistrationID
        INNER JOIN tblData_Measurements M ON V.ID=M.VisitID
```

`ROW_NUMBER()` will create sequences from `1`.

The `PARTITION BY R.ID` says to have separate sequences for each `R.ID`.

The `ORDER BY` determines the order to process the rows when assigning the sequential values.  Having `V.clm_VisitDate,` first ensure that they're in date order.  As some dates have more than one visit, an additional field is also added to the ordering; `V.ID`.  This means that when multiple visits occur on the same date *(for the same person)* the ones with the lowest `V.ID` get the lowest sequence number.